# Error: Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown in get property

Tags: c#

In my model, I use below property

```
 public string LastName
 {
     get => LastName;
     set
     {
         value = value.TrimAndReduce();
     }
 }
```

and I get this error

> System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown

Error is from `get` section of the code

Comment: Yes, your getter calls itself. The setter doesn't do anything, either. Do you have a field that you're trying to use as backing storage for the property? If so, you should have something like `get => _lastName; set => _lastName = value.TrimAndReduce();`

Comment: Is it possible to use it in EF Entites?

Comment: I don't know enough about EF to know that, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a field to store the actual variable of that Property and by accessing `LastName` you call yourself and hence the `StackOverflowException`. The solution is to introduce a field and use the property to access it. Like so:

```cs
private string _lastName;
public string LastName
{
    get => _lastName;
    set
    {
        _lastName= value.TrimAndReduce();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pattern you want, looks like this:

```
private string lastname;  // backing field
public string LastName
{
    get => lastName;
    set
    {
        lastname = value.TrimAndReduce();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When setting the LastName property, you dont invoke the store the actual variable, which invoke a field  `_LastName` and use them.

Solution:

```
public int _LastName;
public int LastName
{
    get
    {
         get => _LastName;
    }

    set
    {
         _LastName= value.TrimAndReduce();
    }
}
```

Comment: His setter doesn't invoke the setter. It just updates the `value` and then throws it away.